# postgresql + textsearch + german umlauts + UTF8

Tags: postgresql, utf-8, full-text-search, diacritics

I'm really at my wits end, with this Problem, and I really hope someone could help me. I am using a Postgresql 9.3. My Database contains mostly german texts but not only, so it's encoded in utf-8. I want to establish a fulltextsearch wich supports german language, nothing special so far.
But the search is behaving really strange,, and I can't find out what I am doing wrong.

So, given the following table given as example

```
select * from test;
      a      
-------------
 ein Baum
 viele Bäume
 Überleben
 Tisch
 Tische
 Café

\d test
   Tabelle »public.test«
Spalte | Typ  | Attribute 
--------+------+-----------
a      | text | 

sintext=# \d
                Liste der Relationen
 Schema |        Name         |   Typ   | Eigentümer 
--------+---------------------+---------+------------
 (...)
 public | test                | Tabelle | paf
```

Now, lets have a look at some textsearch examples:

```
select * from test where to_tsvector('german', a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Baum');
      a      
-------------
 ein Baum
 viele Bäume

select * from test where to_tsvector('german', a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Bäume');
--> No Hits

select * from test where to_tsvector('german', a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Überleben');
--> No Hits

select * from test where to_tsvector('german', a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Tisch');
   a    
--------
 Tisch
 Tische
```

Whereas Tische is Plural of Tisch (table) and Bäume is plural of Baum (tree). So, Obviously Umlauts does not work while textsearch perfoms well.

But what really confuses me is, that a) non-german special characters are matching

```
select * from test where to_tsvector('german', a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Café');
   a   
 ------
  Café
```

and b) if I don't use the german dictionary, there is no Problem with umlauts (but of course no real textsearch as well)

```
select * from test where to_tsvector(a) @@ plainto_tsquery('Bäume');
     a      
-------------
 viele Bäume
```

So, if **I use the german dictionary for Text-Search, just the german special characters do not work?** Seriously? What the hell is wrong here? I Really can't figure it out, please help!

Comment: As SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3d571/4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're explicitly using the German dictionary for the `to_tsvector` calls, but *not* for the `to_tsquery` or `plainto_tsquery` calls. Presumably your default dictionary isn't set to `german`; check with `SHOW default_text_search_config`.

Compare:

```
regress=> select plainto_tsquery('simple', 'Bäume'),
                 plainto_tsquery('english','Bäume'), 
                 plainto_tsquery('german', 'Bäume');
 plainto_tsquery | plainto_tsquery | plainto_tsquery 
-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
 'bäume'         | 'bäume'         | 'baum'
(1 row)
```

The language setting affects word simplification and root extraction, so a vector from one language won't necessarily match a query from another:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('german', 'viele Bäume'), plainto_tsquery('Bäume'),
          to_tsvector('german', 'viele Bäume') @@ plainto_tsquery('Bäume');
    to_tsvector    | plainto_tsquery | ?column? 
-------------------+-----------------+----------
 'baum':2 'viel':1 | 'bäume'         | f
(1 row)
```

If you use a consistent language setting, all is well:

```
regress=> SELECT to_tsvector('german', 'viele Bäume'), plainto_tsquery('german', 'Bäume'),
                 to_tsvector('german', 'viele Bäume') @@ plainto_tsquery('german', 'Bäume');
    to_tsvector    | plainto_tsquery | ?column? 
-------------------+-----------------+----------
 'baum':2 'viel':1 | 'baum'          | t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know how I could oversee that... Now it works perfectly, the day is saved :)